# How can I call another voice command with advanced scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I am writing a voice command using Advanced Scripting in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate). How can I call another voice command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command `HeardWord`.

E.g. if you want to call the command `my voice command` then you can call it from another advanced script as follows:

```
Sub Main
HeardWord "my", "voice", "command"
End Sub
```

Another example, say you want to automatically write down `[name](link)` assuming that you have link as the most recent clipboard and name as the second most recent clipboard (using [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) to manage the clipboard history), you can use the command:

```
Sub Main
    originalClipboard = Clipboard
    SendKeys " ["
    HeardWord "paste", "two"
    Wait(1)
    Clipboard("](" & originalClipboard & ")")
    SendKeys "^v"
    Wait(1)
    Clipboard(originalClipboard)
End Sub
```